# MetaColumns() for a MS SQL view?

Tags: adodb-php

I am trying to use ADODB to work with a MS SQL database containing views.
`MetaColumns()` works well with tables, but returns an empty array when I use a view name as the parameter. Further research shows that `$metaColumnsSQL` uses `sys.tables` object for resolving column names, so it doesn't appear to be intended for views. Is there a way to obtain column names for a view object?

Answer (score 0):

ADOdb cannot provide a metaColumns() object for a view because it's basis is the interrogation of the schema for the objects associated with a single table.

You can emulate  metaColumns() with a view by using the [fetchField()](http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:recordset:fetchfield) method as follows, using NorthWind:

```
$SQL = " CREATE VIEW vEmpTerritories AS
    SELECT employees.employeeId, EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryId
      FROM employees, EmployeeTerritories 
     WHERE EmployeeTerritories.employeeId = employees.employeeId";


$db->execute($SQL);
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM vEmpTerritories"; 

$f = $db->execute($SQL);

$recordSet = $db->Execute($SQL);
$cols = $recordSet->fieldCount();
for($i=0;$i<$cols;$i++){
    $fld = $recordSet->FetchField($i);
    print_r($fld);

}
```

This would return an array of ADOfieldObjects with basic information about each column:

```
ADOFieldObject Object
(
    [name] => employeeId
    [max_length] => 
    [type] => int
    [column_source] => employeeId
)
ADOFieldObject Object
(
    [name] => TerritoryId
    [max_length] => 20
    [type] => nvarchar
    [column_source] => TerritoryId
)
```

Unfortunately, the data returned from fetchfield() is not as detailed as from metaColumns but it may be sufficient for your needs.